# How to service dynamic content with hugo on demand

Tags: hugo

I have a static hugo site, and I would like to add some dynamic content to it. The dynamic content is going to be in the form of some thousands of JSON files which is going to have a template to serve them dynamically.

I understand that I can simply use another technology to serve the dynamic content, but as I love Hugo, I was wondering if I can write a simple function around it to serve the generate dynamic content on demand.

So basically, I am looking for proper function calls in Hugo API to render a template on demand and serve it.

I should mention that due to high change rate of the content, I don't really want to pre-generate all of them.

Comment: Hugo is awesome, but not when you have a lot of dynamic content. If you are willing to change frameworks, I would highly recommend astro (astro.build). It has templates similar to Hugo, and you can use markdown files. It is also very easy to implement dynamic data, the docs are much better than  Hugo's in my opinion, and astro requires much less boilerplate compared to what Hugo requires

Answer (score 0):

Hugo is a static site generator, so it is not designed to work well with dynamic data.

What you could do is having:

1. a Hugo server running on an instance, with a CDN in front of it, configured with a short cache validity for the pages with dynamic data. You refresh the dynamic data in the site `data` folder, or use [remote data using GetJSON/GetCSV](https://gohugo.io/templates/data-templates/#get-remote-data) to pull the data when needed. By doing so, the dynamic pages can get updated on a regular basis. This is better for SEO as the search engines see real content and a frequent update rate.
2. the same setup as previously, but instead of having a Hugo server, you just regenerate the build with a CRON every X minutes/hours.

The alternative is to keep Hugo fully static, and use Javascript to pull the dynamic data and refresh the pages. Less optimal for SEO as the page won't contain the dynamic content, but maybe better for visitors in your case if you have a high change rate of the content or if you want to let them the option to click to refresh the content on demand.

An interesting example of combining Hugo with JS, is Javascript powered search engine for Hugo, using [LunrJS](https://lunrjs.com/). See the [Hugo Learn Theme](https://learn.netlify.app/en/) for an example on how it combines a JSON generated by Hugo with Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

> You can specify your own custom data in templates or shortcodes that pull from both local and dynamic sources.
> Hugo supports loading data from YAML, JSON, XML, and TOML files located in the data directory at the root of your Hugo project.

Hugo also supports loading data from remote sources

> Use getJSON or getCSV to get remote data

https://gohugo.io/templates/data-templates/